Bounds for modulated matrices of finite-elements approximations.
Let $M$ and $W$ be $N\times N$ positive definite symmetric matrices such that for any $\mathbf{f}\in\mathbb{R}^N$,the following inequality hodls $$\mu \mathbf{f}^\top M \mathbf{f}\geq \mathbf{f}^\top W \mathbf{f} \geq \eta \mathbf{f}^\top M \mathbf{f}\qquad (1)$$ for some $\mu>\eta >0$.

Does a constant $c>0$ exist such that  $\mathbf{f}^\top\dfrac{WM^{-1}+M^{-1}W}{2}
   \mathbf{f}\geq c \|\mathbf{f}\|^2$?

My attempt to solve it.
Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an arbitrary eigenvector of $M^{-1}W$ and $\lambda $ the associated eigenvalue. Then,
\begin{align}
\lambda \mathbf{v}=&M^{-1}W\mathbf{v}\\
\lambda M\mathbf{v}=&W\mathbf{v} \qquad (2)
\end{align}
Multiplying (2) by $\mathbf{v}^\top$ at the left, $\lambda \mathbf{v}^\top M\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}^\top W\mathbf{v}$, and since $\mathbf{v}^\top M\mathbf{v}>0$ for any $\mathbf{v}\neq 0$ we get
$$\lambda =\dfrac{\mathbf{v}^\top W\mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{v}^\top M\mathbf{v}}$$
Thus, the inequality (1) leads us to ${\mu \geq \lambda \geq \eta}$. This implies that the eigenvalues of $M^{-1}W$ are bounded from below by $\eta>0$, and as a consequence $\mathbf{f}^\top \dfrac{M^{-1}W+WM^{-1}}{2}\mathbf{f}\geq \eta \|\mathbf{f}\|^2$.
I'm unsure of the last statement.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Here is a counterexample:
$$W=\pmatrix{5&2\\2&1},\quad M^{-1}=\pmatrix{5&-2\\-2&1},\quad\mathbf f=\pmatrix{0\\1}.$$
Since $W$ and $M^{-1}$ (hence also $M$) are positive definite symmetric, they define Euclidean norms on $\Bbb R^2$. On a finite-dimensional space, all norms are equivalent, whence the existence of $\mu,\eta$.

Does the downvoter need more details?

Fixed the "downvoter" .
